# Tire modelling. Problem with sharp edges on tread

Tags: modifiers

I'm modelling high-poly tire with tread. I have problem with sharp edges on tread connection(array+circle modifier). Have you got some ideas to correct it to smooth surface?

[image: tread top view, side and solid]
-----------------------------PROBLEM SOLVED-------------------------------
[image: final result]

Comment: have you tried playing with the order of your modifiers? Try placing the Array Modifier last in the stack (hint: click the down arrow button in the modifier to move its current position). If that still does not help you, I think it wise to begin playing with proportional editing as it has a spherical profile to help with circumstances such as this.

Comment: I tried each order of modifiers before I wrote a question. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are using a curve modifier to bend your array, try increasing its resolution. The default value is 12, but it might not be enough for the kind of detail you need.

[image]

Also, make sure to enable "smooth shading" for the object.

Comment: Thank You for fast answer with photo. I enabled smooth shading before wrote question. I tried your tip and it's work! I know that it's not perfect, but it's fast way to get almost round looking tread. I edited me question by adding photo with result.

Answer (score 0):

[image: InverseSquare Proportional Editing]

To help round out the flat tread sections, I initially though using a spherical profile option in proportional editing would have done the trick, but the Inverse Square profile option proved to be more fitting for me.

To quickly toggle off/on proportional editing...

While in Edit mode hit <kbd>O</kbd>.

Just to the right of this UI toggle there are profile options to choose from.

To adjust influence, scroll your mouse wheel up/down until it begins falling off comfortably.

Comment: Good idea, but in my project I have small pieces of tread. Some parts of it create solid line around circle. That is difficult to get using modifiers. I tried your tip, and I think it can be useful for long pieces of flat elements. Thank You for fast answer with animation!