# How to model a wheel (tyre)

Tags: modeling, workflow

This is how far I got:

[image]

But the tyre is not smooth and has some artifacts on it. If I use more subsurf, it gets more weird.

The steps I took:
The bump map tyre will be of high poly, right? This is what I did:

1. Make a base mesh with high subsurf.
2. Model a patch of seamless pattern (this is very hard) and shrinkwrap it to the base mesh. Here it is:

[image]

3. Array it using empty as offset.

More info: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?442524-Modeling-a-motorcyle-tyre

Can anyone help in in this regard? I am modeling a wheel for harley davidson sporster.

I also tried the Blenderguru's tutorial. Didn't help as his tutorial aims toward different bump.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you need help with? The tyre looks good to me, it is not clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am really sorry if I sound rude, but I am baffled how people cannot read and understand simple question.

First, the title of the questions speaks the question itself: How to model a tyre.

Second, the I wil quote myself: `But the tyre is not smooth` 

Maybe I chose the words wrong, but if you see my first image, you can see it has some sharp edges. This is surely not present in real tyres. So I will be very thankful to anyone who provides me with an answer as to how to model a tyre well.

Comment: "*How ot model a wheel (tyre)*" is a pretty broad and encompassing question to cover here, [according to the rules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If your issue is simply smoothings and sharp edges then it should be worded simply as so. If all you want is a curved shape you may want to model your tire surface with curved surfaces instead of what appears to be two flat planes

Comment: Related. Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/83043/tire-modelling-problem-with-sharp-edges-on-tread/83057#83057

Comment: How are you duplicating the pattern? Are you using Array modifier on curve? If yes, do you check *Merge* and *First Last* in modifier settings?

Comment: @MrZak I did that. Anyway, I figured it out. I used different technique: using lattice to deform. The new tyre is much better.

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a bevel modifier and add it to the top of the modifier stack. It adds more cuts to the edges giving it a more defined look to the overall shape you may be looking for.